# Error in hadoop examples.jar

Tags: hadoop

I just installed Hadoop from the yahoo developers network running on a vm. I ran the following code after start-all.sh after cd-ing to the bin folder

hadoop jar hadoop-0.19.0.-examples.jar pi 10 1000000

I'm getting

> java. io.IOException:Error opening jon jar:hadoop-0.18.0-examples.jar
>   at org.apache.hadoop.util.main(RunJar.java:90) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobShell.run(JobShell.java:54) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobShell.main(JobShell.java:68) caused
>   by:java.util.ZipExcaption:error in opening zip file

How do i sort this out?

Comment: without the error, we don't have anything to go on

Comment: Specify the error , so that you question can be better answered.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the error

Comment: The error is as follows

Comment: java. io.IOException:Error opening jon jar:hadoop-0.18.0-examples.jar
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.main(RunJar.java:90)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobShell.run(JobShell.java:54)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobShell.main(JobShell.java:68)
caused by:java.util.ZipExcaption:error in opening zip file

Comment: at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(NativeMethod)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile<init>(Unknown Source)
           at java.util.jar.JarFile<init>(Unknown Source)    
    at java.util.jar.JarFile<init>(Unknown Source)
           at prg.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:88)
    ...4 more

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that have below things in place

- Your examples.jar file is present in the path where you are running the above command. else you need to give complete path for the jar file.

  hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*example.jar pi 10 100000
- It has appropriate read permissions for the user that you are using to run the hadoop job.

If you still face issue, please update logs in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will face this issue if you are using older version of the java . Hadoop needs Java 7 or Java 8. Please check your JAVA version and update if needed.